# I would like my wifi to turn on and off at certain time each day

Tags: wireless-networking, automation, scheduled-tasks, parental-controls

I would like my WI-fi to turn on and off at a set schedule, so the kids don't use it all night.

I have unplugged the modem, hidden the modem all attempts have failed. How can I do this through the router or computer, so that I can shut down Wifi at a certain time each night?

Comment: There should be some kind of parental controls on the WiFi router's admin page: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-find-your-routers-ip-and-admin/. When you unplug/hide the modem, are they finding it and restoring connection? Or do they have a data connection from their phone so it's not affecting them?

Comment: how does unplugging the modem fail to turn off wifi?

Comment: Please add the make/model of the router, or ISP device to the question. Also please add your children's devices make and models to the question not the comments section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to turn off the wifi connection in my home at night?](https://superuser.com/questions/427652/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-turn-off-the-wifi-connection-in-my-home-at-night)